# Deleting object with template for int and object

Tags: c++, delete-operator

Alright so Say I have a class with all its definition, bla bla bla...

```
template <class DT>
class Foo{
private:
    DT* _data;
    //other stuff;
public:
    Foo(DT* data){ _data = data; }
    virtual ~Foo(){ delete _data; }
    //other methods
};
```

And then I have in the main method:

```
int main(){
    int number = 12;

    Foo<anyRandomClass>* noPrimitiveDataObject = new Foo<anyRandomClass>(new anyRandomClass());
    Foo<int>* intObject = new Foo<int>(number);

    delete noPrimitiveDataObject; //Everything goes just fine.
    delete intObject; //It messes up here, I think because primitive data types such as int are allocated in a different way.

    return 0;
}
```

My question is: What could I do to have both delete statements in the main method work just fine?

P.S.: Although I have not actually compiled/tested this specific code, I have reviewed it extensively (as well as indented), so if you find a mistake, please be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're taking the address of a literal and then calling `delete` on it later, which is wrong.  It was not allocated with `new`, therefore you cannot deallocate it with `delete` (nor would it make any sense to).

If you had written `new int(12)` instead it would be ok, however, there are other problems.

First, your class violates [The Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).  What happens if I copy `intObject` and then call `delete` on both of them?  You end up calling `delete` on the same pointer twice.

Second, why are you allocating these things dynamically to begin with?  You create an RAII style wrapper to handle deallocation for you... and then proceed to allocate it manually.  What problem is that solving?

I suppose this is an exercise for you, and that's great.  Just remember what problem you're trying to solve with this code.

If I am using a `std::vector<T>` I am certainly not going to use it like this:

```
std::vector<int> *v = new std::vector<int>;
```

It defeats the entire purpose of using a vector!  Now I have to manually manage this pointer/memory, and that's the problem that the vector class (and other RAII style classes) were created to solve.

So, to use it properly, you do this:

```
void foo() 
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    // do stuff with v
    // it allocates its memory dynamically so you don't have to.
    // when we exit the function the destructor is called, the memory 
    // deallocated, and life continues as it should.
}
```

Use automatic storage duration to your advantage, that's the whole point.  Also be very clear about who owns the memory. If it is not clear from your class design who owns a given chunk of memory then it is not safe to `delete` it in your destructor.

---

Ok, you changed the code to this now:

```
int number = 12;
// ...
Foo<int>* intObject = new Foo<int>(number);
```

Same problem; you are taking the address of a variable allocated with automatic storage duration and then calling `delete` on it.  **This is wrong**.  Anything you allocate with `new` you deallocate with `delete`, but nothing else.  Ever. That's it.

Comment: I know that it is wrong. Thank you. That is why I made the question. I simply modified the code to make it clearer.
I would use `std::vector` but my professor won't allow us to use it, hence why I have to solve issues that don't exist with `std::vector`.
Also I am doing it this way, because I have a much-MUCH bigger program that tests a data structure that I am creating, and it has encountered this problem. This data structure contains an array of elements, whether int, or any object, and as you may realize, elements are not added or removed all at once.

Comment: @Yokhen: I just used `std::vector` as an example.  What you are attempting to implement is a patter called [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).  There are some problems with your implementation that make it wrong in many circumstances though.  I realize you came here to learn, that's why I answered :)

Answer (score 1):

It seem like you didn't know you can do `new int(12)`. So for example you could change your code to the following:

```
Foo<int>* intObject = new Foo<int>(new int(12));
```

(I'm assuming this is just for learning, as not using `new` altogether would be better).

Also, I just noticed your code is wrong, perhaps you wanted the following:

```
Foo(DT* data){ _data = data; }
virtual ~Foo(){ delete _data; }
```

**Side Note**

Before posting a question, at least try to compile your examples.

Comment: It is for learning purposes, yes. I need to solve this issue for a much bigger program that I have. And I see your point, that could actually work. I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: Fixed the code, thank you. The intend was to have the original object being passed, but I think it doesn't change the problem much if that isn't done.

Comment: @Yokhen: If you intend on using this in production code which will actually be used by other people then you have a few more problems to fix.